# How does FreeRTOS call functions (tasks) using its own heap allocated call stack?

Tags: stack, heap-memory, freertos

As far as I know C compiler uses a stack structure in order to allocate local variables, function arguments, etc, when a function is called.
But FreeRTOS bypass this mechanism and uses its own managed heap to allocate the call stack frame?

The question is: How exactly?
Where do you instruct your compiler/linker in order to use your own memory management scheme for function call stack?

I looked at FreeRTOS source code,  for the targets and compilers I know a little better (ARM and Microchip MCUs; GCC, Keil, IAR compilers), but can't find how this is done.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than diving into the source code, you can read about how the FreeRTOS works here: https://www.freertos.org/implementation/main.html

The compiler/linker know nothing about how the stack is managed by FreeRTOS. The kernel takes care of all the work. This is called [Context Switching](https://www.freertos.org/implementation/a00006.html).

To summarize, when a task is being switched out, the kernel will copy all the required processor registers (i.e. the [Context](https://www.freertos.org/implementation/a00015.html)) into the Task Control Block (TCB). When the task is resumed, the registers are restored from the TCB and the task can continue as if nothing has happened.

[image: FreeRTOS context]

The implementation differs for each architecture. You can check the [AVR port](https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS-Kernel/blob/main/portable/GCC/ATMega323/port.c#L66-L80), as it is relatively simple.